# bad_certificate when migrating app server cluster

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate, appserver

I have set up a cluster of app server in Windows 7. but I want to migrate it to Ubuntu. so I copy the whole packages to ubuntu folder. then I start the service, I received the bad_certificate error. I don't know if I can remove the old cert, and let the browser create a new one?

Comment: and this is not the general case, as I make another copy to another ubuntu 13.04 and works fine.